# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' () to 'NSArray' swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

Why can't cast NSCFNumber (Core Data) to NSArray?

Error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (XXXXXXXX) to 'NSArray'
>   (XXXXXXXX).

Code:

```
//Fetch Settings
    func fetchAccounSetting(){
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("UserSettings", inManagedObjectContext: Context!)
        let request = NSFetchRequest()
        //let data = UserSettings(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: Context)
        request.entity = entityDescription

        var dataObjects: [AnyObject]?

        do {
            dataObjects = try Context?.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch  let error as NSError {
            print(error)
            dataObjects = nil
        }

        for result in dataObjects as! [NSManagedObject] {
            let dataSelected = NSArray(array: result.valueForKey("favCategory")! as! NSArray)
            print(dataSelected)
        }
```

**UPDATE:** 
How can I receive the Count of `dataSelected`?

Comment: You can't cast a number to an array because they are not nearly the same type of object.

Comment: Same reason I can't turn my car into an elephant. It isn't one and saying that it is doesn't make it so. The value for favCategory is an NSNumber, not an array so your forced downcast fails

Comment: Hey, wouldn't your for loop crash if `dataObjects` was nil? (if error occurs and your fetch request throws)

Comment: @KelvinLau Yes - specifically the `as!` assertion would cause a crash if it turned out to be false

Comment: @AaronBrager ty for confirming. Start using `guard` OP!

Comment: I am trying to get the count of my Entity @AaronBrager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data isn't capable of storing arrays or dictionaries in the first place. I remember encountering this problem before as I was learning.

AKA, your `dataObjects` array doesn't have anything that can be typecasted into an `NSArray`. The way to do this is to model a to-many relationship (which creates a `Set`), which can imitate an array.

Answer (score 0):

`result.valueForKey("favCategory")!` is returning a number, but it looks like you're expecting an array.

Perhaps you meant:

```
let dataSelected = [result.valueForKey("favCategory")!]
```

If you know the type you're getting back you can optionally cast it:

```
let dataSelected = [result.valueForKey("favCategory")!]

if let dataSelected = dataSelected as? [NSNumber] {
    // dataSelected is of type [NSNumber] a.k.a. Array<NSNumber>
    print(dataSelected)
}
```

Comment: How can I receive the Count of `dataSelected`?

Comment: When i try `dataSelected.count`, it gives me the last number of selection, not total count.

Comment: No it doesn't, it gives you the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Yes it does, The only thing is different, is when 2 item are in array it would print the first number twice.

Comment: Is that because you're printing it inside a `for` loop?

Comment: Maybe, but even If that, doesn't mean it should print the second number twice as well?